# Multiple Keys to an array in if/else search

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, key

My code is pretty basic. I'm using an array to generate a datasheet for a product based on it's SKU and a filepath.
My array looks like this:

```
$a=array(
"/images/ManualSheets/factSheetCLASSIC.pdf"=>"KE800/6",
"/images/ManualSheets/factSheetMICRO.pdf"=>"KE800/12",
"/images/ManualSheets/factSheetSMALL.pdf"=>"KE4000/12",
"/images/ManualSheets/factSheetMEDIUM.pdf"=>"KE8000/12",
);
```

Where the first Key is the filepath, and the second Key is the SKU (as generated by the system) I then use an if/else to generate a button - so if a product is not in the array it returns a blank value and doesn't have a button which leads to nowhere

```
$factsheetweblink_url =  array_search($product_sku,$a);
if ($factsheetweblink_url==false) {
echo " ";
}
else {
echo "<div class='productpagestockistBTN'>
<a href=",$factsheetweblink_url,"><img src='/images/FactSheet_btn.png' ></a>
</div>";
}
?>
```

This code works fine. The catch comes when I have products with different SKUs but the same datasheet file, (same brand and make but a different model). Currently I can only get it to work by uploading multiple copies of the datasheets with different names, but it's becoming a big waste of space.

I have tried using an array as a key to hold multiple values to the one key..

```
"/images/ManualSheets/factSheetMEDIUM.pdf"=> array("KE8000/12","KE7000/12"),
```

but it doesn't seem to be working... I'm not quite sure if I need to refine my if statement to search within the sub arrays as well or..?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are SKU's unique? Then use the SKU as the key, and the URL as the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrays like this:

```
$products = array(
0 => array(
  "pdf" => "/images/ManualSheets/factSheetCLASSIC.pdf", 
  "skus" => array("KE800/6","KE900/6")
),
1 => array(
  "pdf" => "/images/ManualSheets/factSheetCLASSIC3.pdf", 
  "skus" => array("KE100/6","KE200/6"))
);
```

This is because `array_search` returns just first row whit that key.

Then just do your own search function like:

```
function findBySku($items, $sku) {

  $pdf = ""; // return empty if not found.

  foreach($items as $row) {
    if (in_array($sku, $row['skus'])) {
      $pdf = $row['pdf'];
      break;
    }
  }

  return $pdf;
}
```

and call that function:

```
$pdf = findBySku($products, "some sku");
```

Comment: if you're going to suggest this structure, you need to show him how to search for the SKU, since `array_search` won't do it.

Comment: Thanks for that I'm having a bit of trouble getting it working though. it just doesn't seem to return a value. I changed $sku to $product_sku (which is what the system uses to determine SKU) but I can't seem to get it to return a value.

Comment: Edited my answer to show how function should be called.. If you can't get it work.. debug.. check that the searched sku is in your products array etc.